# Проверка поля при импорте Feeds?

Tags: drupal

Всех приветствую.

Столкнулся с следующей проблемой.
Необходимо дать разрешение пользователям на импорт нод через Feeds.
Одно в полях таблицы нужно обязательно указывать id соответствующей группы, в которую будут добавлены материалы (Entity Reference).

Мне нужно каким то образом проверить два состояния:

1. Существует ли у текущего пользователя группа в которую он импортирует.
2. Принадлежит ли эта группа ему по авторству.

Подскажите как можно решить? Может существует готовый модуль или плагин для Tamper'а.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вряд ли готовое существует.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что никто и никогда не задумывался о проверке импортируемых значений. По умолчанию такого функционала не предусмотрено ни в одном плагине.